# .NET Core - Classe configurada no container com AddSingleton() precisa ser um Singleton?

Tags: .net-core, singleton, .net-standard

Uma aplicação Web API em .NET Core consome uma DLL em .NET Standard. A DLL possui uma classe Foo que depende da classe Bar:

```
class Foo
{
    private readonly IBar bar;
    
    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
        this.bar = bar;
    }
}
```

Bar não é um Singleton (não possui construtor privado e nem .GetInstance()), mas deve possuir apenas uma instância compartilhada por toda a aplicação:

```
class Bar : IBar
{
    public int Contador {get; set;}
}
```

Para tanto, o container da Web API está configurado da seguinte forma:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IBar, Bar>();
}
```

Agora uma aplicação Web em .NET Framework 4.6.1 também precisa consumir essa DLL. Essa aplicação não possui configuração de container. Seguem as questões:

1. Ao instanciar a classe Foo, como garantir que a classe Bar injetada se comporte como Singleton? A classe Bar deveria ter sido implementada como Singleton desde o início?
2. Classe injetada via AddSingleton() precisa ser um Singleton?
3. A configuração da classe Bar no container da Web API, caso fosse um Singleton, ficaria conforme abaixo?

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
services.AddSingleton<IBar, Bar.GetInstance()>();
}

Answer (score 1):

1. Para que a classe Bar se comporte como singleton basta você usar o método `AddSingleton` na hora de configurar os serviços da API. Você não precisa criar GetInstance na classe ou construtores privados isso é cuidado automaticamente pelo framework.
2. A classe injetada via singleton pode ser uma classe "normal". Não precisa seguir o padrão Singleton como se estivesse fazendo na mão. Crie o construtor público com quaisquer dependências que precisem ser resolvidas ou não e os métodos que ela contém. O tempo de vida do objeto será definido quando você for configurar o serviço utilizando os diferentes métodos: `AddSingleton, AddScoped, AddTransient`
3. Para adicionar como singleton, faça: `services.AddSingleton<IBar, Bar>();`. Uma instância única dessa classe será criada durante todo o tempo da aplicação.

Comment: obrigado pelas respostas! Entendi que não é necessário que uma classe seja Singleton para ser configurada pelo AddSingleton() no container, o próprio container se encarrega de tratar uma classe comum como Singleton. Além disso, um ponto importante da dúvida, é como a Web Application, sem possuir um container IoC, pode fazer referência à DLL e manter o comportamento de Singleton da classe Bar? A Web API possui um IoC container, mas a Web Application não.

Comment: Você não pode usar o padrão Singleton pra tentar sincronizar informações entre duas aplicações diferentes. Cada dll vai rodar dentro do escopo da aplicação, não pode acessar de fora. Só se você tivesse outra aplicação no meio fazendo esse controle.

Comment: São duas aplicações (Web Application e Web API) acessando uma Class Library (DLL em .NET Standard), cada uma no seu contexto, uma não tem nada a ver com a outra. Eu não quero que elas compartilhem informações entre si. Eu quero saber como fazer para que a Web Application possa usar a DLL e que a classe Bar se comporte como Singleton, mesmo sem ter um container IoC na Web Application.

Comment: Se o projeto Web App não possui um IoC como nos projetos de Web Api, você pode usar qualquer um dos vários pacotes que existem para gerenciar a injeção de dependência. (SimpleInjector, por exemplo) Aí varia do framework escolhido a forma de implementação, mas via de regra, não deve fugir muito de como é feito no projeto da API. Use o método que te permita registrar o objeto como singleton no framework que você escolheu pra gerenciar as dependencias. Caso não queira usar um framework nesse projeto, você pode criar uma classe wrapper no padrão singleton normal que devolva a classe `Bar`

Comment: Humm acho que estamos chegando no ponto! Poderia dar um exemplo de como seria essa classe wrapper?

Comment: Claro, segue o código no pastebin: https://pastebin.com/kMCQqP3J 
A classe bar continua uma classe "normal", sem o padrão singleton, podendo ser usada no IoC da API pelo `AddSingleton`. Ela se comporta como singleton na API porém precisa de "ajuda" para se comportar como singleton sem ajuda do framework de injeção de dependência. O modo de fazer isso é usando uma classe wrapper.
Da uma pesquisada sobre classe wrapper. A grosso modo, seria uma classe que expõe métodos que estão implementados em outro lugar.

Comment: Obrigado @Leandro Battochio! Acho que isso resolve a questão! Só uma observação, a classe wrapper deve implementar a interface IBar para que possa ser injetada no construtor da classe Foo. O que acha?

Comment: A classe wrapper não precisa ter todos os métodos da classe `Bar`. Somente devolver uma única instância da `Bar` não é suficiente? O que você pode fazer, para ter certeza de que a classe wrapper seguirá o contrato da interface, é alterar o tipo da variavel `mInstance` de `Bar` para `IBar`. Deste modo vai usufruir da abstração da interface como eu acho que você quer. Você pode definir métodos na classe Wrapper se quiser chamar algum método de `IBar` mas adicionar alguma lógica antes do método original, por exemplo. Troque também o `GetInstance` para `IBar`.